# Read the Docs doesn't automatically generate py-modindex.html

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using `sphinx` to document my project. The build-in `index.rst` file has:

```
Indices and tables
------------------

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

which automatically generate a `py-modindex.html` page. This functions very good on my local machine.

So I am trying to host the doc on readthedoc.org. But, what readthedoc do is go to my github, locate the conf.py, generate all html. But since

```
* :ref:`modindex`
```

requires all module importable from local, they may not did that. Hence I cannot see the `py-modindex.html` page. Any idea how to bring it back?

This is my readthedoc page: http://windtalker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

This the page I want (but it's not on): http://windtalker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py-modindex.html

This is github project page: https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/windtalker

Answer (score 1):

I am so stupid... Just enable the virturalenv feature, then my doc can be successfully built